# Не правильно работает метод Object.Instantiate после обновления Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

После обновления *Unity 2017.2.0f3* до версии *2017.3.0f3*, метод [Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) не правильно работает.

```
public GameObject obj;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Inst", 1f, 1.5f);
}

void Inst()
{
    //Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.1f, 2.1f), 6f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

В данном случае мы делаем клон объекта *obj* только с другим *position*.

Но почему-то позиция клона та же самая что и у *obj*.

Comment: Вы меняете global/world position, это то что вы хотите? Если да, можно получить ссылку на GameObject и переместить самостоятельно... Вообще, странное поведение, у меня код работает...

Comment: @test123, я хочу просто сделать клон оъекта с другим transform.position. Так и у меня работал, обновил версию Unity и всё больше не работает.

Answer (score 2):

А что мешает писать вот так:

`GameObject tempObj = Instantiate(obj, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
 tempObj.position = new Vector3(Здесь могла быть ваша реклама);`

Ах да, лучше не обновляйте Unity пока не доделаете ваш проект, иначе многое придётся подгонять под новые версии, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: Можно и это решение проблемы:) Но зачем писать две стоки если можно одну, и хочеться просто разобраться, что не так.